# jQuery RegEx. If string contains any character except

Tags: javascript, regex

I've got this RegEx which is used to validate what the user enters

It must be a value 8 - 16 characters long and can contain ONE of the certain special characters.

```
/^(?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[:;#~]).{8,16}$"
```

I'm not trying to show an alert if the user enters something that doesn't match the above. So a-z, A-Z, 0-9 and `:;#~` are allowed but anything else shows an alert.

So `Abcd1234#` is OK, but if they enter `Abcd1234!$` if will show the alert as `!` & `$` are not in the match.

I've tried adding ^ to the start of character match to try and negate them, but that didn't work.

What's the best way to do this?

Comment: You mean you want to only allow the chars mentioned in the lookaheads? [`/^(?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[:;#~])[\da-zA-Z:;#~]{8,16}$/`](https://regex101.com/r/4MRGaW/1)?

Comment: can contain or must contain ??? your regex ensures it must have A-Z but you said abcd1234# is ok

Comment: Why should `abcd1234#` match if you require an uppercase ASCII letter? It should not match.

Comment: the input needs to be 8-16 characters long, MUST contain lower AND upper case letters, digits and any of the special characters. Anything else should show the alert.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems you only need to allow the characters mentioned in the lookaheads, create a character class with them and replace the last `.` with it:

```
/^(?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[:;#~])[\da-zA-Z:;#~]{8,16}$/
                                            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/4MRGaW/3)

The `[\da-zA-Z:;#~]{8,16}` pattern will match 8 to 16 chars that are either digits, ASCII letters, or `:`, `;`, `#` or `~` symbols.

**Details**:

- `^` - start of string
- `(?=.*\d)` - there must be a digit after any 0+ chars other than line break chars (a `(?=\D*\d)` will be more efficient as it is based on the [**contrast principle**](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-style.html#contrast))
- `(?=.*[a-z])` - - there must be an ASCII lowercase letter after any 0+ chars other than line break chars (a `(?=[^a-z]*[a-z])` will be more efficient)
- `(?=.*[A-Z])` - there must be an ASCII uppercase letter after any 0+ chars other than line break chars (a `(?=[^A-Z]*[A-Z])` will be more efficient)
- `(?=.*[:;#~])` - there must be a `:`, `;`, `#` or `~` after any 0+ chars other than line break chars (you may also use `(?=[^:;#~]*[:;#~])`)
- `[\da-zA-Z:;#~]{8,16}` - 8 to 16 chars defined in the character class
- `$`  - end of string.

Comment: Thanks this seems to do what I need. is there a site which will break this down and explain what it all means ?

Comment: Sorry missed that. Thanks